# Multiple authentication types in Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

We have an API service which has multiple APIs exposed, and there are multiple personas who/which can access our service.

1. Users - Who needs to have an account in our system -> Needs to be
   authenticated with our Identity Provider Service (Keycloak) with JWT
   token.
2. Regulated System - Which needs to be authenticated with central 
   authority maintained by some party.
3. Internal service to service communication -> authentication with same 
   Keycloak.
4. Temporary JWT token issued by the same service before creating the user 
   account when the user digitally verified the mobile number.

I was trying to have **AuthenticationWebFilter** for each authentication type, and configure with Pathmatchers, though it was getting authenticated by the right authentication web filter, the request keeps flowing through the other authentication filter, and ends up resulting as `unauthorized`.

Snippet of configuration:

```java
public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                                         @Qualifier("userCreationFilter")
                                                                 AuthenticationWebFilter userCreationFilter) {
        final String[] WHITELISTED_URLS = {"/**.json",
                                           "/users/verify",
                                           "/users/permit",
                                           "/sessions",
                                           "/internal/xxxxx/**",
                                           "/**.html",
                                           "/**.js",
                                           "/**.yaml",
                                           "/**.css",
                                           "/**.png"};
        httpSecurity.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(WHITELISTED_URLS).permitAll();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(userCreationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/users")
                .authenticated();
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable().csrf().disable().logout().disable();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain2(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                                          @Qualifier("managerFilter")
                                                                  AuthenticationWebFilter managerFilter) {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(managerFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/xxxxx/**",
                        "/providers",
                        "/xxxxx/**/approve",
                        "/xxxx/**/xxxxx").authenticated();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Right now there are no roles as such we have.

I tried keeping all configuration in single SecurityWebFilterChain Bean, and tried addWebFilterAt, but no luck.

What am I missing? Should I do it different way?

Comment: 1. and 3. are the same thing and should be treated the exact same way. "Regulated System" is not a standard name for anything so what you are talking about here i have no clue. 4 is a temporary token and should be treated like any other token. I have absolutely no idea why there is a need to complicate something to the point that its just a lot of overhead. Use the built in JWT filter in Spring security and fetch a jwk from the single authority, use that jwk to verify the integrity of the token.

Comment: use a single issuer, that issuer issues all tokens, you fetch that issuers jwk and just verify all tokens. Set scopes and check the scopes if they are allowed or not to call the expected endpoint.

Comment: Agree that 1 and 3 are same, me too thinking to do authentication in the same way for these too.

What I meant as Regulated system is there is a central authority, for example `Federal Reserve System` where all the banks and financial parties need to have an account for themselves, if someone needs to access few of our APIs, they should have authenticated themselves with FRS, get JWT Token, and use that for accessing these APIs. Please do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: For 4th one, I'm able to verify the token and authenticate. I'm able to achieve what I want, the problem is I have one single `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` with single `SecurityContextRepository`, where I manually check what is the URL and check the respective issuer, I would like to keep things bit more organised.

Comment: Hello, if you found the answer, share the solution, I also have the same error

Comment: @IsoqHakimov https://github.com/ProjectEKA/consent-manager/blob/cfd93de77f7360d533d5ba27a364c35d5bf5533d/consent/src/main/java/in/projecteka/consentmanager/SecurityConfiguration.java#L209 I was able to achieve it like this only at that point of time.